# Airflow Docker Unhealthy trigerrer

Tags: docker, airflow

Im trying to setup airflow on my machine using docker and the docker-compose file provided by airflow here : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                                                 NAMES
d4d8de8f7782   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)     8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-scheduler_1
3315f125949c   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)     8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-worker_1
2426795cb59f   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp             airflow_airflow-webserver_1
cf649cd645bb   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-triggerer_1
fa6b181113ae   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)     0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, :::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   airflow_flower_1
b6e05f63aa2c   postgres:13            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes (healthy)          5432/tcp                                              airflow_postgres_1
177475be25a3   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes (healthy)          6379/tcp                                              airflow_redis_1
```

I followed all steps as described in this URL, every airflow component is working great but the airflow trigerrer shows an unhealthy status :/

Im kinda new to docker i just know the basics and i don't really know how to debug that, can anyone help me up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow all steps on their website including `mkdir ./dags ./logs ./plugins echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env`.

I don't know but it works then, but still unhealthy,

[airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

Comment: Hello, I already tried that but the trigger status is still unhealthy :/

Comment: It's unhealthy but is no problem with that status, will still work's fine

Comment: Oh okay, and do you know how can i fix the unhealthy status and what causes it ?

Comment: This unhealty status has been a problem in a while, not sure what's the problem with it

Comment: Same problem here. I got the feeling it is somehow related to this error: ```Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'plyvel'```